# How to use an object created inside a try block, outside of it?

Tags: c++, oop, exception, try-catch

Say I created an object inside a try block because I wanted to catch the exceptions thrown from it's constructor, how will I be able to use the object outside of that block?

```
//Inputs given to t5 can throw an exception from the constructor.
    try {
        Time t5(23, 59, 59);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e) {
        cerr << "\n\nException while initializing t5: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
```

In the case where an exception is thrown, I probably won't need to use it but in a case where it isn't thrown, I'll surely need it afterwards but an object created inside a block isn't accessible outside.
One solution I could think of was creating the object outside of block and then assigning an R-value object to it I create by explicitly calling the constructor like this:

```
    Time t5;
    try {
        t5 = Time(23, 59, 59);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e) {
        cerr << "\n\nException while initializing t5: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
```

But this is doing unnecessary stuff like creating another object just for trying to catch an exception.
Are there any better ways to do it? Also, is throwing exceptions from a constructor a bad programming practice?
PS: I saw a similar question being asked but for C# and also, the solution given there is the same that I came up with but I believe that there should be a better way as I explained above.
Thank you.

Comment: *"Also, is throwing exceptions from a constructor a bad programming practice"* - It's the only way to report errors from constructors. Anybody who says otherwise is going to suggest contortions to your code that are themselves bad from a design point.

Comment: There's nothing special about a `try` block here; the problem is simply that an object defined inside a block is not visible outside that block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on what kind of a default constructor `Time` has. If its constructor just zeroes three numbers, then your solution is ok.

If its default constructor is expensive (or doesn't exist at all), you can put it into [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional):

```
std::optional<Time> t5;
try
{
    t5.emplace(23, 59, 59);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Yeah it zeroes everything out but what do you mean by expensive? like allocating memory on heap? Also, I'll study std::optional too now that I know it exists.

Comment: @SaadAhmed allocation on heap isn't always expensive. Expensive means using two much memory

Comment: @SaadAhmed Yep, I would consider allocating on the heap expensive enough to switch to `optional`, which doesn't use heap.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think we really can access it outside the try block.

Two ways to solve the problem.

1. Best is to include the usage of Time t5 inside the try block.
2. Make use of std::optional

```
   std::optional<Time> t5;
    try
    {
        t5.emplace(23, 59, 59);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e) {
        //exception message
    }

    if(t5)
    {
        //use t5
    }
```